# Edit URL before redirect

Tags: javascript, html, query-string

Here  I am stuck with a scenario where I want to edit `href` of `anchor tag` before redirect. My scenario is if `href` attribute of `anchor tag` do not contain `QueryString` then append previous page query string to `href` means, suppose my current page url is `xyz?x=2&y=4`
**Current href**

```
href="local/services"
```

**After Edit**

```
href="local/services?x=2&y=4"
```

I tried.

HTML:

```
<a href="http://localhost/services" onclick="appendString(this)">test link </a>
```

JavaScript

```
function appendString(obj) {
   var url = obj.getAttribute('href');
    if (url.indexOf('?') != -1)
      obj.setAttribute('href') = url + window.location.search;
    }
```

also tried

```
function appendString(obj) {
    var url = obj.getAttribute('href');
     if (url.indexOf('?') != -1)
         window.location.href =  url + window.location.search;
      }
```

but no success.
Please suggest a solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jed Burke pointed to your mistake. So you should use something like this:

```
function appendString(obj) {
    var url = obj.getAttribute('href');
    if (url.indexOf('?') != -1) obj.setAttribute('href', url + window.location.search);
}
```

or even simpler:

```
function appendString(obj) {
    if (obj.href.indexOf('?') != -1) obj.href += window.location.search;
}
```

Comment: are you sure `obj.href` has `?` in it?

Comment: Then it should be `if (url.indexOf('?') == -1)`.

Comment: Ha, yes, fresh eye can help sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

The parameters for 'setAttribute' are incorrect.

> element.setAttribute(name, value);

Courtesy MDN : [Element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute)

Comment: `obj.setAttribute("href", url + window.location.search);` still redirecting to page without QS

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery for this:

```
$('.myLink').click(function() {
$(this).attr("href", this.href + "?param=1");
});
```

Comment: 1. I asked for `Java Script`
2. Sorry, because for some reasons I cant use class.